# I have Landsat 8 level 1 data in different date to cover entire region after mosaicking the complete images there is found to be distinct color

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat-8, image-mosaic

[image]

How can I find a proper solution?

Comment: Hi @Sandeep and welcome to the GIS.stack exchange community. 
If you want answers to your question, you should take some editing steps before. 
- change the title so it reflects your question only 
- add a complete description of your problem in the body of your post

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.